# CImg error unhandled exception stack overflow 

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cimg

When I run my code on Visual Studio 2010, I get: `Unhandled exception at 0x00b38767 in thesis.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow`.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "CImg.h"
#define cimg_use_jpg
using namespace cimg_library;
int main () {
CImg<int> image("C:\Users\Echo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thesis\thesissample\thesis\thesis\maze1.jpg");
CImgDisplay main_disp(image,"Image",0);

return 0;
}
```

I haven't been able to find any explanation or tutorial which would allow me to get past this. I've also tried running a `png` file but I also get the same error. I'm running Visual Studio 2010 on 64 bit Windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: The tutorials I saw used "CImg<unsigned char>", not "CImg<int>". Not sure if that makes a difference. http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html Also, how large is your image? What if you use "CImg<T> *image = new CImg<T>(...);".

Comment: I'm guessing that `cimg_use_jpg` is used by the header file `"CImg.h"`? In that case you should place the `#define` _before_ you include the file, otherwise the header file will not see it.

Comment: Shouldn't the path be given with forward slashes instead of backslashes. Backslashes will turn the character into some other ascii caracter, for example the \t (\thesis) will become a "tab"-space

Answer (score 0):

i think it's like this
 #define cimg_use_jpeg